# Cannot connect to AWS RDS Postgres with pg8000 but good with psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, amazon-rds, psycopg2, pg8000

friends,

I'm trying to connect to a Postgres instance in AWS RDS from python script running in an EC2 machine. It's working well with psycopg2/sqlalchemy as

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine 
import psycopg2

db_string = 'postgresql+psycopg2://{user}:{password}@{host}:5432/{database}'.format(
        user=DB_USER,
        password=DB_PASS,
        host=DB_HOST,
        database=DB_NAME)

engine = create_engine(db_string, echo=True)    
conn = engine.connect()
```

But it failed when I use pg8000/sqlalchemy as

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine 
import pg8000

db_string = 'postgresql+pg8000://{user}:{password}@{host}:5432/{database}'.format(
        user=DB_USER,
        password=DB_PASS,
        host=DB_HOST,
        database=DB_NAME)

 engine = create_engine(db_string, echo=True)    
 conn = engine.connect()
```

The error info is

```
InterfaceError: (pg8000.exceptions.InterfaceError) {'S': 'FATAL', 'V': 'FATAL', 'C': '28000', 'M': 'no pg_hba.conf entry for host "*.*.*.*", user "*", database "*", SSL off', 'F': 'auth.c', 'L': '513', 'R': 'ClientAuthentication'}
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/14/rvf5)
```

I also tried to set the `connect_args={'ssl_context': True}` but still failed on the connection. Anyone has any thoughts? I'm using python v3.6, sqlalchemy v1.4.15, and pg8000 v1.19.4.
Thank you.

Comment: My bad. ssl_context is for pg8000. Thanks.

Comment: When you add the `ssl_context:True`, I assume the error message changes?  That is the error you need to pay attention to.

Answer (score 0):

As of pg8000 1.31.0, by default an [SSL connection will be attempted](https://github.com/tlocke/pg8000#connect-to-postgresql-over-ssl) using lenient settings, so it should work in the same way as psycopg.

Answer (score -1):

The value for the `ssl_context` key is typically created with `ssl.create_default_context()`.

By default that uses the trust the system’s default CA certificates. One can also download AWS's certificate bundle (a global one, or one of the region specific variants. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/UsingWithRDS.SSL.html#UsingWithRDS.SSL.CertificatesAllRegions). And then set the parameter `cafile`. E.g. Something like this:

```py
import ssl
from os import path

# This snippet uses sqlmodel's create_engine which uses sqlalchemy under the hood.
from sqlmodel import Session, create_engine

# assume that the PEM file is in the same directory as current python script file.
ssl_server_certs_path = path.join(path.dirname(__file__), "global-bundle.pem")

engine = create_engine(
        config_uri,
        connect_args={"ssl_context": ssl.create_default_context(cafile=ssl_server_certs_path)})
```